# Browser does not save authentication cookie obtained from CORS request

Tags: cors, session-cookies, couchdb-2.0

==== PROBLEM SOLVED ====

The problem described below was caused by the fact that the property 'withCredentials' was not set properly on the underlying xhr request object. This we cannot see from the trace of requests and responses given below.

For Purescript users: the Affjax library convenience functions (put, get, etc.) rely on a defaultRequest object that sets this property to false.

========================

In the scenario given below in terms of requests and responses the browser first authenticates and then tries to create a database in Couchdb.

The origin resides on http://127.0.0.1, the server on http://127.0.0.1:5984 and so the request is considered to be cross-domain.

This fails with an error indicating that the client is not authenticated. However, as far as the server is concerned, the client IS authenticated: it sends an AuthSession cookie. The problem is that the browser does not return that cookie with the database create request. Indeed, I cannot find the cookie through any of the Chrome interfaces: it is not stored.

I am completely at a loss as to why. I checked the CORS specification (https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-sharing-check-0) and as far as I can see, all requirements for the cookie to be accepted are met.
The origin domain of the request is http://127.0.0.1 and this domain is in the content of the   Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. 
The requested header is in the content of the Access-Control-Allow-Headers header.
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials is "true".

PREFLIGHT AUTHENTICATION REQUEST TO COUCHDB

```
OPTIONS /_session HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:5984
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://127.0.0.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: nl-NL,nl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
```

RESPONSE

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
X-CouchDB-Body-Time: 0
X-Couch-Request-ID: a307303b47
Server: CouchDB/2.1.1 (Erlang OTP/19)
Date: Wed, 28 Feb 2018 08:28:07 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Access-Control-Max-Age: 600
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://127.0.0.1
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, HEAD, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

ACTUAL AUTHENTICATION REQUEST

```
POST /_session HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:5984
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 35
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Origin: http://127.0.0.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: */*
Referer: http://127.0.0.1/dist/index.html?user=cor&password=geheim
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: nl-NL,nl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
```

RESPONSE

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Set-Cookie: AuthSession=YWRtaW46NUE5NjY4MTc6DBUWBuYmEGnyuJvrpic7Z6DEiko; Version=1; Path=/; HttpOnly
Server: CouchDB/2.1.1 (Erlang OTP/19)
Date: Wed, 28 Feb 2018 08:28:07 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 46
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: content-type, cache-control, accept-ranges, etag, server, x-couch-request-id, x-couch-update-newrev, x-couchdb-body-time
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://127.0.0.1
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

PREFLIGHT REQUEST TO CREATE DATABASE IN COUCHDB

```
OPTIONS /_node/couchdb@localhost/_config/admins/cor HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:5984
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT
Origin: http://127.0.0.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: nl-NL,nl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
```

RESPONSE

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
X-CouchDB-Body-Time: 0
X-Couch-Request-ID: bd94200e3e
Server: CouchDB/2.1.1 (Erlang OTP/19)
Date: Wed, 28 Feb 2018 08:28:07 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Access-Control-Max-Age: 600
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://127.0.0.1
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, HEAD, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

ACTUAL REQUEST

```
PUT /_node/couchdb@localhost/_config/admins/cor HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:5984
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 8
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Origin: http://127.0.0.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: */*
Referer: http://127.0.0.1/dist/index.html?user=cor&password=geheim
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: nl-NL,nl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
```

RESPONSE

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
X-CouchDB-Body-Time: 0
X-Couch-Request-ID: 6eabdacc77
Server: CouchDB/2.1.1 (Erlang OTP/19)
Date: Wed, 28 Feb 2018 08:28:07 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 64
Connection: close
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: content-type, cache-control, accept-ranges, etag, server, x-couch-request-id, x-couch-update-newrev, x-couchdb-body-time
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://127.0.0.1
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

Comment: Maybe you have some privacy settings active in the browser that prevents the cookie from being saved. Did you try a profile without any extensions and with default settings?

Comment: @t.niese Thank you. I did and found no difference. As a matter of fact, both Chrome and Safari give the same results...

Answer (score 1):

The problem described below was caused by the fact that the property 'withCredentials' was not set properly on the underlying xhr request object. This we cannot see from the trace of requests and responses given below.

For Purescript users: the Affjax library convenience functions (put, get, etc.) rely on a defaultRequest object that sets this property to false.